# Como exibir somente objetos setados como true em uma nova activity

Tags: java, android

Tenho aqui um arraylist que é mostrado em um listview, quando dou clique longo um dialogo é exibido la contem a opção de favorito que quando é selecionada o obejeto é marcado como verdadeiro, como faço para exibir somente os itens marcados em minha ActivityFavoritos?

### MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    ArrayList<memes> item;
    ArrayAdapter<memes> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_main);

        lv = findViewById(R.id.lv);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        item = new ArrayList<>();
        //itens
        item.add(new memes("Fique apertado sobre o meme para compartilhar", R.raw.sharebagui));
        item.add(new memes("2 mil anos", R.raw.milanos));
        item.add(new memes("Acelera jesus", R.raw.acelera_jesus));
        item.add(new memes("Azideia", R.raw.asideia));
        item.add(new memes("Acertou mizeravi", R.raw.mizeravi));

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        //play audio
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                playSong(position);
            }
        });
  //PROGRESS

        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long l) {
           //PROGRESS
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Olá, Marilene!");
            builder.setItems(Nomes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0: // Delete
                            sendWhatsAppAudio(position);
                            break;
                        case 1: // Copy
                            item.get(position).setmIsFavourite(true);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });


            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            builder.show();

            return true;

        }
    });
    }

    public void playSong(int songIndex) {

        mp.reset();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, arrayAdapter.getItem(songIndex).getResId());

        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }

}
```

### memes.class

```
    public class memes{

    private String nome;
    private int resID;
    private Boolean mIsFavourite;

    memes(String nome, int resID){

        this.nome = nome;
        this.resID = resID;
    }

    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }

    int getResId(){
        return resID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return nome;
    }

    public Boolean getmIsFavourite() {
        return mIsFavourite;
    }

    public void setmIsFavourite(Boolean mIsFavouriteResource) {
        this.mIsFavourite = mIsFavouriteResource;
    }

}
```

### ActivityFavoritos.class

```
public class ActivityFavoritos {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_favoritos);

        lv = findViewById(R.id.lvf);

        if (list.get(position).getmIsFavourite()) {
            //do want you want when its true
        } else {
            //do want your code when its false.
        }

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não está muito clara, poderia explicar melhor seu problema!

Comment: @NayronMorais Quero fazer um esquema de favoritos, para isso na MainActivity nessa parte `case 1:
                            item.get(position).setmIsFavourite(true);
                            break;` eu seto os itens com true, e quero recupera-los na ActivityFavoritos somente os marcados como true, mas n sei como fazer isso. E se no caso de um milagre eu consegui exibir os itens em um listview na activity favoritos, tenho outra duvida, vou ter que reescrever o mediaplayer na activity favoritos para eles reproduzirem?

Comment: Não conseguirá fazer o que deseja da forma que está fazendo, no caso, utilizando os Adapters padrão, terá que criar seu próprio Adapter estendendo de Adapter. E, dentro de seu adapter implementar a lógica que deseja!

Answer (score 0):

Veja os exemplos a seguir:

Primeiramente você deve criar seu próprio layout para o item da lista:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_list_item"
    android:background="@color/colorItemListView"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/item_list_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/item_list_padding"


        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/questionMoreOptions"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_more"
            android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"

            />

        <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/colorDialogGridLayout"
            android:columnCount="4"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:useDefaultMargins="true"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"

            >



            <!-- Primeira Parte (Números de Visualizações e Respostas -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/appCompatImageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_message"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numberAnswers"
                style="@style/textLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"


                />


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/appCompatImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_eye"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"


                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numberViews"
                style="@style/textLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/sizeAnswersExample"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"

                />


            <!-- Fim da Primeira Parte -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleQuestion"
                style="@style/textPrimary"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                android:gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:ellipsize="end"

                />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleArea"
                style="@style/textLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:lines="1"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"






                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameUserQuestion"
                style="@style/textLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:lines="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="2"
                android:gravity="right|top"
                android:layout_gravity="right"

                />



        </GridLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Depos implementar seu próprio adapter,  no método **getView()** você deve colocar a lógica para ocultar o item da lista, é neste método que é gerada a view que representa cada item, note que neste exemplo estou usando o padrão ViewHolder para atrelar melhor desempenho reutilizando os itens já criados.
Para ocultar o item da lista sugiro que dê uma olhada neste tópico: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041499/how-to-hide-an-item-in-a-listview-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041499/how-to-hide-an-item-in-a-listview-in-android://)

```
public class QuestionsListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create();

private String baseUrl;
private List<Question> questions;
private Activity activity;

public QuestionsListViewAdapter(List<Question> questions, Activity activity) {

    this.activity = activity;
    this.questions = questions;

    baseUrl = activity.getResources().getString(R.string.SERVER_URL) + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.SERVER_QUESTIONS) + "deleteQuestion";

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return questions.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return questions.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return questions.get(position).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    Question question = questions.get(position);


    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity.getBaseContext());


        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_questions, parent, false);

        viewHolder.numberAnswers = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberAnswers);
        viewHolder.numberViews = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberViews);
        viewHolder.titleQuestion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleQuestion);
        viewHolder.titleArea = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleArea);
        viewHolder.nameUser = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameUserQuestion);
        viewHolder.moreOptions = (AppCompatImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.questionMoreOptions);

        viewHolder.moreOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showPopup(v, position);
            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }
    try {

        viewHolder.numberAnswers.setText(String.valueOf(question.getNumberAnswers()));
        viewHolder.numberViews.setText(String.valueOf(question.getNumberViews()));
        viewHolder.titleQuestion.setText(String.valueOf(question.getTitleQuestion()));
        viewHolder.titleArea.setText(question.getTitleArea());
        viewHolder.nameUser.setText(String.valueOf("@" + question.getUser().getUserKey()));



    }catch (Exception e){

    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Depois é só criar uma instância de seu Adapter na Activity alvo, e setá-la em sua listiview.